TinyLlama after training is not giving desired results
I am learning to train tinyllama, on my own small (SmallDataSet) dataset, using the Unsloth notebook.
Here is my notebook customized to my small dataset: Notebook
Please advice why it is not able to answer instructions its trained on.
And how do I fix this issue ?
